# How to get error HTTP status code in react admin

Tags: javascript, http, error-handling, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework and I am trying to get error status code (404,500), which I would be saving to some variable for later usage. For example, when I try to create an `user` that has same e-mail address as already created `user`, the server wont allow this operation and the request fails with `status code 500`. 
I need that status code to save to variable and work with it later.

Does `react-admin` offer this?

So far I have tried this simple code in my custom `DataProvider`, but when logging it to console, it returns `undefined`.

```
const status = params.message.status;
```

I wasn't able to find any other solution that I would fully understand.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is what are you looking for:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status

First of all, you actually need to request some data from the server in order to get the `response.status` code. 
The most simple example would be this based on the link I listed before:

```
var myRequest = new Request(options.body); //depends on what do you want to request
fetch(myRequest).then(function (response) { //gets the response from server
  console.log(response.status, 'status'); // this returns the status value
});
```

This should return the `response.status` code.